# How to convert UTM coordinates to WGS 84 in R

Tags: r, gis, arcgis

I have the following example dataset

```
library(mgrs)
library(sf)

id = 1:4
UTM.MAP.COORDINATE <- c("49PBT230126", "49PBT020440", "49PBT320320", "49PBT000270")

df <- data.frame (id, UTM.MAP.COORDINATE)
```

Please can you help me project the UTM coordinates to WGS 84 format.

I have tried to do the following

```
library(sf)

df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = "UTM.MAP.COORDINATE", crs = st_crs("+proj=utm +zone=48N +datum=WGS84"))
```

But I am getting this error message

```
Error in st_as_sf.data.frame(df, coords = "UTM.MAP.COORDINATE", crs = st_crs("+proj=utm +zone=48N +datum=WGS84")) : 
  missing values in coordinates not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
In lapply(x[coords], as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Thank you.

Comment: It really helps when you provide actual usable data, this code does not parse. For instance, an obvious one is `object 'YD400540' not found`. If you have a string vector, then please make a string vector. _**EDIT**: please actually **run** your code, it still has a clear error._ ... Forget it, I will edit your code for you to make this question actually _parse_ correctly.

Comment: Further, UTM coordinates like this needs another identifier, `YD400540` does not uniquely define a point, you also need grid identifiers. See https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-are-utm-coordinates-measured-usgs-topographic-maps and https://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/2001/0077/report.pdf

Comment: @r2evans I believe this is in Military Grid Reference System format

Comment: Yes it is MGRS ... and it is still incomplete. You need a grid identifier for those coordinates.

Comment: Do you know what country/province/state those coordinates are in?

Comment: They are for Vietnam

Comment: You probably want `48N` as a grid identifier, see https://epsg.io/3405; for instance, `48N YD 400 540` is the "full"/proper first element. From there, use [`site:stackoverflow.com convert utm to coordinates "R" "mgrs"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%253Astackoverflow.com+convert+utm+to+coordinates+%22R%22+%22mgrs%22) to see many related (duplicate) questions on SO about converting UTM and MGRS to latitude/longitude in R.